# How to correctly proxy jump with SSH

Tags: ssh, proxy

I need to proxy jump with SSH in the following way:
`me --> user1@ip1 --> user2@ip2`.

What i did up to now is to create a key pair for `user1@ip1` and
I can avoid inserting the password for the first user by running:
`me -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_user1 -J user1@ip1 user2@ip2`.

I still need to prompt the password for the second user.
What is the correct way to use key pairs to ssh with a proxy jump, in order to avoid insering passwords?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could configure it in your ~/.ssh/config

```
HOST host1
   hostname ip1
   user user1
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_user1

HOST host2
   hostname ip2
   user user2
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_user2
   ProxyJump host1
```

Then you can use

```
ssh host2
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear answer!
For macos users in order to make your key work in `~/.ssh/config` file, you have to add it with `ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa_user<n>`.

Comment: How would this config file change if there were no ssh key for host2 and it needed to be accessed with myUserName/MyPassword (but host1 has the key in place and is working fine from the client)?

Comment: @AndrewWard Nothing, or you could remove the `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_user2` but ssh will just ask for the password for user2, when no private/public key fits